# Meteor: Difference between request.query and request.body in restFul API

Tags: rest, meteor

while using restFul Api in meteor, we return two request methods `request.body` and `request.query` for get and post methods:

```
Utility = {
    getRequestContents: function(request) {
        switch (request.method) {
            case "GET":
                return request.query;

            case "POST":
                return request.body;
            }
        },
```

But I am not getting the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology comes from HTTP. HTTP GET requests are made to *get* or *query* something, that is why they don't have a "[body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body)", but a "[query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)" string. POST has a body (the thing that should be *POST*ed), but it does not (usually) have a query.

Normally the two have different purposes and it is actually a questionable idea to mix them into a generic "content" term.